# allow column based sorting on gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

There is this grid-view which has two columns that needs to be sorted.

The problem is i am getting a list of class to bind the data to gridview data source, On click of grid column the sort expression fires but the data source is null, so how can i achieve this.

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDelegateList" runat="server" CssClass="gridviewBorder" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true"
                    EmptyDataText="There are no delegates assigned for this bridge." CellPadding="2"
                    Style="margin-left: 0px" BackColor="White" Font-Names="Calibri" BorderWidth="1px"
                    Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="Horizontal" RowHoverBackColor="#666666"
                    RowHoverForeColor="White" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#333333" SelectedRowStyle-ForeColor="White"
                    PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="grdDelegateList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="grdDelegateList_RowCommand"
                    OnRowDataBound="grdDelegateList_RowDataBound" 
                    OnRowDeleting="grdDelegateList_RowDeleting" onsorting="grdDelegateList_Sorting">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee ID" DataField="DelegateID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="DelegateID"
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Display Name" DataField="FullName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" SortExpression="FullName"
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <span style="cursor: pointer">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="ImgRemove" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                                        Text="Remove" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this Delegate');">
                                        <img alt="Remove" src="Images/trash.png" style="border:0;" />
                                    </asp:LinkButton></span>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

Sort Expression event:

```
 protected void grdDelegateList_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable table = grdDelegateList.DataSource as DataTable;//this is coming                 null

            if (table != null)
            {
                DataView dataView = new DataView(table);
                dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

                grdDelegateList.DataSource = dataView;
                grdDelegateList.DataBind();
            }
        }

private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

            switch (sortDirection)
            {
                case SortDirection.Ascending:
                    newSortDirection = "ASC";
                    break;

                case SortDirection.Descending:
                    newSortDirection = "DESC";
                    break;
            }

            return newSortDirection;
        }
```

Since the data source is null ,do i need to fetch the data from db again,if yes i am fetching a list , so do i need to add the cutom logic to first convert the list to a data-table or will it work with list too. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting null because the datasource is list and not a datatable in current scenario. So it would be better When you're binding the grid use the converted datatable from list. Rest of your sorting logic would remain unaffected.

**Update:**

Keep the datatable in the session. Retrieve and rebind the grid in sorting event after sorting the datatable from session. Also don't forget to update the session table as well with updated sort expression. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx

Comment: the list of the class has an object of other class that is needed to fetch the information of that class.so datatable will not work...

Comment: Then you should use cast the datasource to list instead of Datatable and perform sorting on list items.

Comment: i have made changes in the code now it is fetching data table but in sorting expression event the griddatasource is still null..